# UITableView section headers drawing above front subview

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview

I have a UITableView whose data have sections. I display an overlay view on top of tableView that dims it when searching:

```
- (UIView *)blackOverlay {
    if (!blackOverlay) {
        blackOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[self overlayFrame]];
        blackOverlay.alpha = 0.75;
        blackOverlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor;
        [tableView insertSubview:blackOverlay aboveSubview:self.parentViewController.view];
    }
    return blackOverlay;
}
```

This works perfectly as long as tableView does not contain sections. When tableView does contain sections and the tableView updates (such as when the view reappears after popping a view off of the navigation controller stack), the section headers are rendered above blackOverlay. This leaves tableView dimmed except for the section headers. I've tried calling `[tableView bringSubviewToFront:self.blackOverlay]` from within `viewWillAppear:`, but I get the same behavior.

My current work-around is returning nil for tableView section headers while the overlay is present, but this leaves whitespace gaps in the overlaid tableView where the section headers were previously.

How can I insure that tableView section headers are never drawn above blackOverlay? Or, is it possible to create a view in front of tableView from within a UITableViewController subclass that is not a subview of tableView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your function should be tweaked a bit. If you're returning an object that was `alloc`'d but not `autorelease`'d, then your method name should indicate that (i.e. `newBlackOverlay`). Second, your method is modifying a `tableView` object that was not given to it, so its interactions with other components is not obvious (see [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)).

The problem is that you're putting this black overlay as a child of the table view. You should be inserting it at the same level of the table view, i.e.:

```
UIView (set to the view controller's view)
|
+-UITableView
|
+-UIView (your new black overlay)
```

You can create it inside Interface Builder and set the `backgroundColor`/`alpha` properties as you see fit. Create a new `UIView` `@property` in your view controller and set it to your new `UIView`. Then you can change the overlay's `alpha` value and/or hide it completely in your callback functions for when the user starts/ends searching tasks.

> I have a UITableView whose data have
>   sections. I display an overlay view on
>   top of tableView that dims it when
>   searching

FWIW, in case you don't know, you can build search screens fairly easily with the new [`UISearchDisplayController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class Apple introduced in iPhone OS 3.x. Might save you re-inventing the wheel, here.

Comment: I should have specified that blackOverlay is actually a lazy-loaded read-only property, so the object is actually managing its memory. Thank you for referring me to the UISearchDisplayController. I was unaware of its existence and indeed it appears that I'm reinventing the wheel!

Comment: FYI, the UISearchDisplayController draws directly on the tableView too if given a TableViewController as its contentsController.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a root view controller and making my table view a subview of this controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create the root view to hold the table view and an overlay
    UIView *root = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.view.frame];
    root.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    root.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.view = root;

    // Setup the table view
    UITableView *newTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    newTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.tableView = newTableView;
    [newTableView release];
    [root addSubview:self.tableView];

    [root release];
}
```

I was then able to use a `UISearchDisplayController` with a search bar at the top of the tableView without issue.